# mysql case then unrecognized keyword and unrecognized token

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to understand why is this mysql query having error on phpmyadmin Version: 4.7.1.Please see attached screenshot. I read about problem with the version of phpmyadmin then I upgrade my phpmyadmin to the latest but still get this error in mysql. It says unrecognized keyword and unrecognized token when as I check I have a valid sql.

```
select
      case 
        when venue like '% aklan %' then 'usa'
        when venue like '% italy %' then 'italy'
        when venue like '% china %' then 'china'
        when venue like '% india %' then 'india'
      end as cvenue,
      count(*) as population
    from 
        (
          select concat(' ', venue, ' ') as venue
          from tbl_trainings
        ) T
    group by cvenue
```

[image]

Comment: Try changing `count(*)` to `count (*)` It may be relying on [this configuration](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ignore_space) IF this is the problem of course

Comment: Why the subselect instead of selecting directly from the table?

Comment: @SloanThrasher presumably to avoid repeating the concat expression for each when clause

Comment: @propaganja: First of all there is no need of inner select query. Second please share your table structure for `tbl_trainings`. You may get a solution with simple query.

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: Server version: 5.7.14 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Comment: @keyur hi. Thanks for the input but I needed the subquery so that I can group them

Comment: @propaganja: You are using mysql, right ? Group by will work without inner one.

Comment: @SloanThrasher to give you as brief idea of my goal on this query. I have a table with venue column that is a string. either the word I am looking for is at the end or at the start or in the middle of the string.

Comment: @SloanThrasher yes thank you for pointing that out. I was stuck in the concat from my previous test. I really appreciate all your help. Updated my code.

Comment: @propaganja: You don't need to append one extra space at start as well as at end and then use LIKE. LIKE will work without that because `%` is wildcard character which means `0 or more characters`. You can check my answer.

Comment: Please post a solution as an answer to the question, not as an update to your question. That is to help future visitors understand and to avoid confusion. If it wasn't a solution please don't call it one. Instead use Code: to again avoid confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to put your case statement in bracket. Then execute query:

```
select
      (case 
        when venue like '% aklan %' then 'usa'
        when venue like '% italy %' then 'italy'
        when venue like '% china %' then 'china'
        when venue like '% india %' then 'india'
      end) as cvenue,
      count(*) as population
    from 
        (
          select concat(' ', venue, ' ') as venue
          from tbl_trainings
        ) T
    group by cvenue
```

Comment: Why do you think that will help?  If it does help, what specifically caused the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Try below query. This will give you same output and will be better in performance as you have no extra INNER query:

```
select
 (case when venue like '%aklan%' then 'usa'
   when venue like '%italy%' then 'italy'
   when venue like '%china%' then 'china'
   when venue like '%india%' then 'india'
 END) as cvenue,
count(*) as population
from tbl_trainings
group by cvenue;
```

Even if your contry name is at start or at end, you don't need to append one extra space at start as well as at end and then use LIKE. LIKE will work without that because `%` is wildcard character which means `0 or more characters`.